# Relating Derivative with Output

Tags: calculus

The derivative of the function $Y = X^2$ is $Y'= 2X$.

I interpret the derivative as the change in y due to a change in x.

I am confused on how to use the derivative to see what the next value of $X^2$ will be.

At $X = 2$, $X^2 = 4$ and derivative is equal to $1$.

At $X = 3$, $X^2 = 9$ and derivative is equal to $4$.

Why doesn't the below equation work?

$Y(2) + Y'(2) = 4+ 4 = 8$ which I expected to equal Y(3)

but $Y(3)=9$.

Comment: My mistake, fixed it. Interesting technique below, I somewhat recall the name but will dig deeper. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You´re welcome. If you have any additional question to that issue feel free to ask. You can mark the answer as accepted if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method  is a linear approximation: $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)\cdot (x-a)$.

In your case it is $f(3)\approx 2^2+4=8$. But this is an approximation only. It is better to work with the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to get the value at $x=3$

$$f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+ \cdots$$

$f(x)=x^2, f{'}(x)=2x, f{''}(x)=2$. The following derivatives are $0$.

$$f(3)=f(2)+\frac {f'(2)}{1!} (3-2)+ \frac{f''(2)}{2!} (3-2)^2$$

$$=2^2+\frac{2\cdot 2}{1!}\cdot (3-2)+\frac{2}{2!}\cdot (3-2)^2$$

$=4+4+1=9$